# Syntax Error for if statement in Lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, python-3.7

targetScore is the maxvalue from a list of integers. 
I use the lambda function with map. For every value in the function, I want lambda to append it to a list 'ListofIndices' if the item is equal to the maxvalue from the list.

When I try to define:

```
getter = lambda x: listofIndices.append(index(x)) if x == targetScore
```

Im getting the error statement:

```
getter = lambda x: listofIndices.append(index(x)) if x == targetScore                                                                   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I am not sure that is valid Python syntax. Please add more context on how you plan to use this lambda.

Comment: What value do you expect when ``x == targetScore`` [is not true](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)?

Comment: The if-expression needs an "else". An if-statement isn't allowed in a lambda.

Comment: Sorry for lack of context. targetScore is the maxvalue from a list of integers. I use the lambda function with map. For every value in the function, I want lambda to append it to a list ListofIndices if the item is equal to the maxvalue from the list.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a list comprehension, not `map`. You can't return values conditionally with `map`.

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide more of that context? It seems like the problem here is using a lambda with map for a side effect.

Comment: `append()` returns `None`, it modifies the list in place. So it's not useful in `map`.

Comment: You're also using `index()` wrong. It should be `some_list.index(x)`. And `index()` always returns the first matching index, so you're not going to get all the indexes of the target score.

Comment: Yeah, I think when you write 'for every value I want to append the value to a list of indices if the item is equal to the maxvalue from the list', you can see that you could do this with a `for` statement easily inside of a function. Maybe try defining a function that does this, instead of using lambda's? There are lots of ways to do it, but start with something basic then refine that if you want to use more advanced features.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://treyhunner.com/2018/09/stop-writing-lambda-expressions/#Misuse:_naming_lambda_expressions) it may help your thinking about using a lambda here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need both a filter *and* a map, which would require two different functions: one for the condition and one for the transformation. You can use a list comprehension to get the same effect:

```
listOfIndices = [i for i, x in enumerate(integers) if x == targetScore]
```

`enumerate` iterates through (index, element) pairs, so you don't have to use the `index` method.